# ILogger don't log when object is injected

Tags: c#, .net

I'm not able to identify the reason why my ILogger interface doesn't log anything when the object is injected, but when it is built with a new() everything works normally.

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
        ILogger logger;

        [ActivatorUtilitiesConstructor]
        public Foo(ILogger<Foo> logger)
        {
            this.logger = logger;
        }
        public Foo(ILogger logger)
        {
            this.logger = logger;
        }
        public void testLog()
        {
            logger?.LogInformation("xxxx");
        }
}
```

```
public class Bar
{
   private ILogger<Bar> _logger;
   private IFoo foo;
   public Bar(ILogger<Bar> logger, IFoo foo)
   {
       _logger = logger;
       this.foo = foo;
   }
    
   public void test(string bla)
   {
       IFoo foo1 = new Foo(_logger);
       foo.testlog(); //this print "xxxx"
       
       foo.testlog(); //this dont print "xxxx"
   }
```

My startup

```
services.AddTransient<IFoo, Foo>();
services.AddTransient<IBar, Bar>();
```

Comment: You need to explicitly register logger instance e.g. `services.AddSingleton<ILogger<Bar>, LoggerClassImplementation);`

Comment: You code will not even compile (`IFoo foo1 = new(_logger);` for example due to type mismatch.).